# Scala: lazy stream causing error: forward ref

Tags: scala, functional-programming, stream

I have created a Stream object as follows:

```
object Stream {
  def cons[A](hd: => A, tl: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] = {
  lazy val head = hd
  lazy val tail = tl
  Cons(() => head, () => tail)
}

def empty[A]: Stream[A] = Empty

}
```

When I then use this to create a stream which is lazy I've seen an error (which I don't understand) when the stream is created inside a function but not when declared as a instance value...

```
object testStream {
  val myStream: Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(72, myStream) // OK

  def doStuff: Unit = 
    val xStream: Stream[String] = Stream.cons(" start ", xStream) // Error: forward reference extends over definition

}
```

Why does this error occur, is this due to the value being declaired in a function and as a result it is being evaluated rather than being lazy interpreted?

Comment: can you please add tha error log?

Comment: the problem is the statement which is causing the error is in the method

Comment: @RamanMishra The error reported is: `Error:(85, 58) forward reference extends over definition of value xStream
    val xStream: Stream[String] = Stream.cons(" start ", xStream)`

Comment: methods comes into the memory only when it calls so the val xStream is not in memory and you are using it that's the problem.